# "Den Akku laden" vs. "den Akku aufladen"

Tags: meaning, difference

In vielen Blogs im Internet habe ich gemerkt, dass man beide Ausdrücke verwenden kann, wenn man über das Handy spricht. Gibt es aber irgendeinen Unterschied zwischen ihnen?

Zum Beispiel:

> 1. Ich muss den Akku meines Handys laden.
> 2. Ich muss den Akku meines Handys aufladen.

Haben die beiden Sätze die gleiche Bedeutung? Können sie austauschbar verwendet werden?

Comment: @HalvarF, oh danke sehr!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kurz und knapp: ja, die Sätze haben die gleiche Bedeutung und können je nach Gewohnheit austauschbar verwendet werden, ich sehe keinen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Verben in diesem Zusammenhang.

Answer (score 6):

### Haben die beiden Sätze die gleiche Bedeutung? Können sie austauschbar verwendet werden?

Ja zu beidem. Hier eine Übersicht einiger Wörterbuchdefinitionen:

| Wörterbuch | *laden* | *aufladen* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Duden | ≈ aufladen ([Nr. 5](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/laden_packen_befrachten#bedeutungen)) | ≈ laden ([Nr. 2a](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aufladen#bedeutungen)) |
| DWDS | elektrische Energie speichern ([Nr. 3](https://www.dwds.de/wb/laden#d-1-3)) | etw. mit elektrischer Ladung versehen ([Nr.2](https://www.dwds.de/wb/aufladen#d-1-2)) |
| Wiktionary | einen Akkumulator (Akku) oder Kondensator mit elektrischer Energie auffüllen ([Nr. 5](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/laden#Verb)) | etwas mit elektrischer Energie versehen ([Nr. 3)](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/aufladen) |

### Gibt es aber irgendeinen Unterschied zwischen ihnen?

- Technisch gesehen: Nein. Akku laden = Akku aufladen = Strom fließt in den Akku.
- Grammatikalisch: Kleine Unterschiede gibt es, die sich jedoch meistens nicht auf die Verwendung auswirken. Im Einzelnen sind das:

#### Bedeutung

Die Vorsilbe *auf-* fügt dem Verb verschiedene Bedeutungskomponenten hinzu, vgl. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/auf-#wb-1):

> **auf-** (Affix, verbal)
>
> (1) drückt eine aufsteigende Richtung aus
>
> - (f) etw. füllig, prall machen
>
> (7) drückt ein Ergebnis, die Vollendung einer Tätigkeit
>
> (8) drückt ein Erneuern aus

*Aufladen* kann somit als das betonte Gegenteil von *entladen* verstanden werden. Außerdem ist *aufladen* deshalb besonders dazu geeignet, die [Aktionsart](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aktionsart) von *den Akku vollmachen* auszudrücken, da es sich dabei um eine [faktitive](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faktitiv) Aktion handelt.

#### Konjugation

Wenn *aufladen* faktitiv gebraucht wird, ergibt sich in Aktivsätzen ohne [Agens](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agens_(Linguistik)) eine andere [Valenzalternation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valenzalternation) als beim nicht-faktitiven *laden*:

| Aktivsatz enthält… | *laden* (atelisch verwendet) | *aufladen* (faktitiv verwendet) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Agens und Patiens | Ich lade den Akku meines Handys. | Ich lade den Akku meines Handys auf. |
| nur Agens | Ich lade. | Ich lade auf. |
| **nur Patiens** | **Der Akku meines Handys lädt.** | **Der Akku meines Handys lädt *sich* auf.** |

Das vorher transitive Verb ***laden*** wird hier intransitiv, das [Patiens](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patiens) (*Akku*) wird zum Subjekt eines Aktivsatzes. Solche Verben nennt man *ambitransitiv*.

Die faktitiv gebrauchte Verbform ***aufladen*** hingegen bildet den [Antikausativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikausativ), der durch das Reflexivpronomen *sich* markiert wird. Noch deutlicher und häufiger ist diese Alternation wohl beim Verb *entladen*.

Comment: @HalvarF: Wäre ich spitzfindig würde ich einwenden, dass es Geräte ohne Akku gibt, die aufladbar sind, z.B. solche mit einem Kondensator. ;) Ob sich "laden" verbietet, wenn zugleich mehr entladen als geladen wird, bezweifle ich. Natürlich kann das missverständlich sein, aber es kann aus dem Kontext ja klar sein, dass zeitgleich der Akku netto Ladung verliert. Wie sonst will man diesen nichttrivialen Sachverhalt sprachlich ausdrücken? Was sagt man, wenn man gar nicht weiß, ob netto mehr geladen als entladen wird?

Comment: @userunknown: mein Kommentar bezog sich auf eine ältere Version der Antwort, in der es noch hieß, das Wort "laden" würde auch netto-entladen umfassen, "aufladen" aber nicht. Hat sich erledigt.

Answer (score 1):

"Ich muss den Akku meines Handys laden." means to charge it.

"Ich muss den Akku meines Handys aufladen." strictly speaking means to load it onto something.

Germans use both expressions for the first meaning, because the latter doesn't make any sense, unless you have a real big cellphone battery.